flutter_recaptcha_v2_compat not responsive on Android
currently I'm encoutering this issue in using flutter_recaptcha_v2_compat. the reponsive of heigh it doesn't work. Please any one here can assit me? and I have no solution with this part
Bugs layout not reponsive on Android.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
